# How to run an exported selenium test case using TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng, selenium-ide

I recorded a test case using Selenium IDE 1.10.0. I exported the case as Java/TestNG/Remote Control.

My Eclipse version is 4.2.0 and I installed TestNG plug-in version 6.8

I am wondering how can I create a project within the eclipse to run this exported test case?

Please give me some instructions or share with me some online tutorial / documentations. Thanks!

Below is the java code generated by the Eclipse:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SearchDonor extends SeleneseTestNgHelper {
    @Test public void testSearchDonor() throws Exception {
        // set overall speed of the test case
        selenium.setSpeed("4000");
        selenium.open("/?html=openid");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"submit\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        selenium.click("id=cmp_admin");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=quicksearch_anchor");
        selenium.click("css=img[alt=\"Member\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("id=search_name", "suzy");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"image\"]");
        selenium.click("link=Balagia, Suzy");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and errors. I managed to execute the exported code in Eclipse as TestNG Test. Here are the steps I took to make it compile.

1.created a Java Project within the Eclipse

2.add a class to the Java Project

```
2a. I copied and pasted the code into the newly created the class
```

3.Right click on the project>build path>configure build path

3a. on the Java Build Path window select libraries>Add External JARS, then adding all the JAR files from Selenium Java Driver folder (e.g. folder name in this case is libs), plus selenium-java-2.31.0.jar and selenium-java-2.31-src.jar

4.click the Run icon next the debug icon on the top menu bar, Run AS TestNG Test

My code is compiling, but I got some exception errors. I am getting stared on a TestNG test case!